# Form: enable textarea if radio button is selected

Tags: forms, radio-button, textarea

How can user input other address in the textarea when select the radio button for "Others Address" as below 4 options :

```html
<br><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 1" checked> Address 1
<br><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 2">  Address 2
<br><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 3">  Address 3
<br><input type="radio" name="br_address" value=""> Others Address
<br><textarea name="br_address" rows="3" cols="40" disabled></textarea>
```

Thank you very much for your help & support first !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some javascript to toggle the textarea when the other address field is checked.  Something like this would work:

**HTML**

```
<br><label><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 1" checked> Address 1</label>
<br><label><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 2">  Address 2</label>
<br><label><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="Address 3">  Address 3</label>
<br><label><input type="radio" name="br_address" value="" id="addressOther"> Others Address</label>
<br><textarea name="br_address" rows="3" cols="40" disabled id="addressField"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var addressOther = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="br_address"]');
var addressField = document.getElementById('addressField');
var tempAddress = "";

for(var i = 0; i < addressOther.length; i++) {
    addressOther[i].addEventListener("change", addressHandler);
}


function addressHandler() {
    if(this.id == "addressOther") {
    addressField.disabled = false;
    addressField.value = tempAddress;
  } else {
    tempAddress = addressField.value;
    addressField.value = "";
    addressField.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/pkqm6f52/

Hope that helps!